# ImportError: cannot import name 'final' from 'typing'

Tags: python, import, typing

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3086]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\xolo-sniper-recode-main

C:\Users\user\Desktop\xolo-sniper-recode-main>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in 
from typing import final
ImportError: cannot import name 'final' from 'typing' (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\typing.py)

C:\Users\user\Desktop\xolo-sniper-recode-main>

i am trying to run a python file named main

Comment: You're using Python 3.7, that's new in Python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[final](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.final) was added in Python 3.8. You can see this in the documentation underneath the text describing its usage. You can either upgrade your Python interpreter to 3.8+ or you can omit final.

You may find it helpful to switch the documentation version at the top of the page to 3.7 so that it doesn't show features that you can't use in Python 3.7.

Comment: OP may find it more useful to upgrade from the now-end-of-life Python 3.7.